# Android DDMS view not available in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on porting a game I made to android (never programmed on android before) and want the android DDMS for profiling, as shown in [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#running) but the view is not available in eclipse (no DDMS in Show View -> Other) even though the SDK manager reports it is installed and I can run usb debug mode on my phone from eclipse just fine.

How do I set up the debug view shown in the picture above in Juno?

Comment: Have you tried in Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS? That's what it says in the doc

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid now, I have been coding 15+ hours daily last couple of weeks I can't read anymore!

Comment: @KenWolf you should put this as the actual answer. Reputation for having it accepted aside, many people don't read the comment, and this is the fix!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not in Show view it is in "Open Perspective"

Just do the following

From Eclipse: Click Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS.